Writing horizontally right-to-left
In this text, Keiten-aijin (敬天愛人), "revere heaven, love people", a calligraphy by Saigō Takamori, why is it written from right to left?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts

I remember an anecdote from my first Japanese Teacher in 8th grade: back then, when Japan started to write in horizontal lines, they would do both left-to-right and right-to-left; he said that he was looking at a text on a taxi cab and that the characters mirrored on both sides of the car. Over time the left-to-right for horizontal text was standardized.

Traditionally, Japanese is up-to-down, right-to-left.
